# Programming the game of life?

Tags: factorio

At [2:00 in the official trailer](https://youtu.be/KVvXv1Z6EY8?t=1m48s), the narrator explains that you can "even program the game of life, if you like".

**What does this mean ?**

Is he referring to a game feature ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He is referring to [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life).

The Game of Life is interesting because it is both simple and [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), so it is a good indicator of Factorio's level of flexibility (on par with that of Minecraft's redstone circuitry, for example).

Comment: On a side note, is there any evidence that the narrator is telling the truth and its proven that is possible or somebody has done it already?

Comment: @Sergii The video clearly shows a GoL simulation.  Whether it's real is another matter.

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta: It is actually not difficult to make a system Turing Complete _(meaning it can compute anything a computer can, given enough time)_. For example, [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) is a Turing Complete programming language with only 8 instructions.  Minecraft's redstone is dead-simple, and it is Turing Complete.  This game's logic circuits are much more powerful than Minecraft's, making it easy to prove they are indeed Turing Complete.

Comment: @Kevin - Many of the factories seen in the gameplay trailer are from saved games uploaded to the official forums before the Steam launch. [I found one save](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=13997) that plays a simplified GoL.

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta Beyond the GoL, I recently ran across a game of [Pacman programmed in Factorio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VR_b9YwqH8).